# Case structure with many WHEN Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (TestTable) with data as below

[image]

I need to create a calculated column "Band" based on ColA,Age,Gender column values. like below

```
 CASE

 WHEN ColA='A' AND AGE=1 AND GENDER='M' THEN 'BANDX90'
 WHEN ColA='A' AND AGE=1 AND GENDER='F' THEN 'BANDX91'
 .
 .
 .
 .
 WHEN ColA='A' AND AGE=65 AND GENDER='M' THEN 'BANDX18'
 WHEN ColA='A' AND AGE=65 AND GENDER='F' THEN 'BANDX19'
 WHEN ColA='B' AND AGE=1  AND GENDER='M' THEN 'BANDX39'
 WHEN ColA='B' AND AGE=1  AND GENDER='F' THEN 'BANDX56'  
 ELSE NULL
 END AS BAND
```

Note:My user/client had provided me the BAND values('BANDX90',.... )for **different** WHEN conditions in an excel sheet.

The disadvantage with the above CASE method is, If i have 500 records in the table then i have to use the `CASE 'WHEN' STMT 500 TIMES` which is not a good option.

Did anybody faced the same situation while calculating a column? If yes, please share your advices!

Is there any other way we can accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any Logic for **`BANDX??`**

Comment: some restrictions on my network hides the image from me. So if possible can you please type the columns ?

Comment: There is no logic.My user/client had provided me the BAND values('BANDX90',.... )for different WHEN conditions in an excel sheet.

Comment: @oOoTesting1oOo please check my anwser.

Comment: @oOoTesting1oOo are you storing the BAND values somewhere ? If the client changes something in the excel you need to go and edit the query ?

Comment: hi VeekayBee... Thanks for the response... I am not storing the BAND values anywhere. I have to just use the excel file to see the BAND values and put them in the case when stmt for appropriate condition.

Comment: @oOoTesting1oOo : See my answer. If there is any problem then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no logic for `BANDX__` then better you use a column in table which will be your `Then` statement.

**[Here is SQLFiddelDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25b90)**

**Below is the Pic which show my opinion :**

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on this answer? Maybe add a little bit of SQL here?

Answer (score 5):

> My user/client had provided me the BAND values('BANDX90',.... )for different WHEN conditions in an excel sheet.

I think it would be easy to put this **BAND values** information in `table(BandValues)` with header like

```
Col1 Age Gender Band_Value
```

Not the logic:

```
Update T
Set T.Band = B.Band_Value
From Testtable T
INNER JOIN BandValues B
ON T.Col1=B.Col1
AND T.Age=B.Age
AND T.Gender=B.Gender
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Luv!! I cannot use join because Testtable is a summary(groupby) table

Comment: if you can provide Exact columns of Testtable I will be able to solve.

Comment: @oOoTesting1oOo - storing this data in a table and performing some form of join or lookup is definitely the way to go. You can use a subquery or CTE to perform the `GROUP BY` step "first"